# How to remove a given static IP from a different network?

Tags: networking, ip, nas

I have a NAS drive and it has a static IP (192.168.0.10 and DHCP disabled). I need to connect it to my Home network (its IP setting is 192.168.8.x and DHCP enabled).So they are two different network settings.
How can I access the NAS through my Home network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using following steps.
1. Log in to the Home router. 
2. Disable its DHCP and give IP settings (Subnet, Default Gateway, DNS,..) of the office to the Home router.
3. Attach the NAS to the Home network 
4. Log into the NAS and enable its DHCP.
5. Log in back to the Home router and enable its DHCP